# NP-hardness of problem with indices and subsets

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

Consider the following problem.

> Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and $A_{ij}\subseteq S$ for $i,j\in S$. Does there exist a *strict* subset $T\subset S$ such that for all $j\not\in T$, there exists $i\in T$ for which $T\subseteq A_{ij}$?

(For $T=S$, this is trivially true, so we disallow it.)

The problem is in NP: given a set $T$, it is easy to verify whether it satisfies the property. Is it also NP-hard, or does there exist a polytime algorithm?

I tried to construct such a set $T$ greedily by starting with some $i\in S$. If $i\in A_{ij}$ for all $j\not\in i$, we can choose $T=\{i\}$ and are done. Otherwise, there is some $j$ for which $i\not\in A_{ij}$, so we can try adding $j$ into the set, and iterate on the new set $T=\{ij\}$ until the process stops. The problem is that there is no guarantee that this will stop before $T$ is the whole set $S$ even if such $T\neq S$ exists.

I also thought about dynamic programming, but it's not clear what the subproblems should be in this setting. On the NP-hardness side, I thought about reducing from some problems related to sets. There are problems like subset-sum or partition, but those concern sums of elements and are not directly relevant.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: @Raphael I've added my attempts. Please let me know if this is still not sufficient :)

Comment: (a) Suppose $\forall i,j . 1 \notin A_{i,j}$.  What constraints on $T$ can you encode by choosing $A_{1,1},\dots,A_{n,1}$ appropriately?  (b) Suppose $\forall i . A_{i,1} = \emptyset$.  What constraints on $T$ does this encode?    (c) Can you do anything with this?  What class of constraints on $T$ can you encode using these kinds of ideas?  Does this give you any ideas?

Comment: @D.W. For (a), we can conclude that $1\not\in T$, since if $1\in T$ we must have $1\not\in A_{i,j}$ for some $i,j$. For (b), we can conclude that $1\in T$, since if $1\not\in T$ we must have $T\subseteq A_{i,1}=\emptyset$. Combining (a) and (b), we have that if both conditions are satisfied, then no subset $T$ exists. I'm not sure what we can conclude from here, though.

Comment: Nope, you haven't thought about (a) enough. Keep working at it. If you choose the $A_{i,1}$ cleverly, you can encode more sophisticated constraints than $1 \notin T$. Also, I'm not suggesting you apply (a) + (b) together to the same column; e.g., you could apply (a) to column 1 and (b) to column 2. Anyway, I've given you a direction. Keep working to see what types of constraints you are able to encode.  Then, edit your question to show the full set of constraints you've been able to express in your problem.  Then, think about whether this helps you find a reduction (to prove NP-completeness).

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for your hints. I still don't understand the high-level idea, though. How does encoding these constraints help with proving NP-completeness? Even if we can encode constraints like $\{1,2,3\}\in T$ or $\{4,5\}\not\in T$, or even something like $T=\{1,3,5\}$ or no $T$ exists, how does this lead to a reduction?

Comment: If you can reduce a NP-complete problem to your problem, you've proved your problem is NP-complete.  Can you think of any well-known NP-complete problem that involves looking for something that satisfies a bunch of constraints?  Or, to put it another way: think of the problem "find $T$ that satisfies a bunch of constraints".  Is that NP-complete?  (The answer will depend on the types of constraints that you are allowed to use.)  If the answer is yes, and if you can reduce that to your problem, then you've proven your problem is NP-complete.

Comment: @D.W. I think you're referring to SAT, where we have constraints like $(x_1\vee\neg x_4\vee x_5)\wedge(x_2\vee\neg x_3)\wedge\dots$. Here $x_i$ would mean that $i\in T$. Now, we need to encode something like "$1\in T$ or $4\not\in T$ or $5\in T$". For each of $1\in T$ and $4\not\in T$, etc., we can already do this as above. But if we just combine the condition, we get a statement with "and" instead of "or". How can we encode "or"?

Comment: @D.W. I'm thinking about reducing to 3-SAT, so the types of constraints we need to encode are "$1\in T$ or $2\in T$ or $3\in T$" and combinations with $\not\in$ instead of $\in$. But when I add a constraint $1\not\in A_{i,j}$ for all $i,j$ like you suggest, this already implies $1\not\in T$, without any "or"s. Also, this constraint affects all sets $A_{i,j}$, not only those in the first column, so I'm afraid that it will affect later constraints (assuming that we use $1$ SAT constraint = $1$ column.) I'm really confused about these two points.

Answer (score 1):

This question shows that Vašek Chvátal is a hero.

Reduce from graph kernel.

In the **GRAPH KERNEL** problem, the input data is a digraph and the task is to determine whether it has a kernel.

A kernel of a digraph is a subset $S$ of its vertex set which satisfies **(i)** no two vertices of $S$ are adjacent, and **(ii)** for every vertex not in $S$ there exists an arc from some vertex in $S$ pointing to it.

So, we need to transform a digraph to your **set matrix** problem.

For each original vertex, create an element. Call these elements vertex-elements. Denote this set of element by $V$.

For each original arc, create an element. Call these elements arc-elements.

Now, to ensure $T$ is an independent set in this digraph. For each arc-element $a=(u,v)$, set $A[u,a]=V\setminus\{v\}$ and $A[v,a]=V\setminus\{u\}$. Also, just in case none of $u$ and $v$ is included in $T$, for every $w\neq u, v$, set $A[w,a]=V\setminus\{u,v\}$.

To ensure $T$ is a dominating set in a digraph, for each arc $a=(u,v)$ set $A[u,v]=V$

All the other entries of $A$ are set to $\emptyset$.